# «По зрелом размышлении» — в каких случаях обособляется оборот?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Чаще всего выражение ***по зрелом размышлении*** не выделяется запятыми, но иногда встречается и его обособление.

*Другая отличительная черта единовластия Петра состояла в умении прислушиваться к дельному совету и отступить от своего решения, если оно, **по зрелом размышлении**, неверно или вредно, — черта, совершенно отсутствующая у Карла...*
[*С. Цветков. Забытые истории*](https://sergeytsvetkov.livejournal.com/265338.html)

*А потом, **по зрелом размышлении**, пожалела, да было поздно — пришлось следом за новоиспеченным супружником нырять в морские волны и обустраивать придонный быт.*
[*О. Вайнгарт. Латышские народные сказки*](https://www.rubaltic.ru/article/kultura-i-istoriya/26092017-latyshskie-narodnye-skazki/)

*Потом, **по зрелом размышлении**, отправили несостоявшегося паломника под надзор компетентных органов на остров Родос.*
[*Д. Бриг. Сражение при Зенте*](https://hist-etnol.livejournal.com/5928756.html)

Поясните, пожалуйста, в каких случаях обособляется оборот?
Верна ли пунктуация в примерах?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые в предложенных примерах не связаны с узнаваемостью конкретного выражения и проистекают из более общих правил. В первом примере - явный ***вводный*** оборот, поскольку "зрелое размышление" нельзя отнести к обстоятельству действий того, что обозначено местоимением "оно". В двух других случаях имеет место ***уточнение***: когда именно "потом".
Если же данный конкретный оборот можно отнести к явному производителю действия, то он эквивалентен *обстоятельству* его совершения, и обособлять не нужно:

> По зрелом размышлении (после долгих раздумий) **она** пожалела...
>
> По зрелом размышлении (после долгих раздумий) **они** отправили

В безличных конструкциях для определения "вводности" (и соотв. необходимости в обособлении), по всей видимости, может иметь значение, к кому по смыслу хотят отнести "размышления" (к себе как к автору или к неназванному производителю действия):

> По зрелом размышлении можно [кто-то после раздумий может] счесть это неверным или
>   вредным.
>
> По зрелом размышлении [я подумал - это на мой взгляд], можно [я склонен или кто-то - не из числа зрело поразмысливших - мог бы] счесть это
>   неверным или вредным.